# Binding Converter and multibinding

Tags: wpf

I want to create 4 rectangles stacked to one row.

|----|--|------|------------|

The width of every rectangle is binded to value in %.

I decided to group rectangles to horizontal StackPanel. To calculate the width of the rectangle I want to write convertor.

What I don't know is how to create converter that must be binded to:
- value in %
I want to pass the width of parent to converter parameter.

How to write parameter to bind it to parent's width?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to know how to calculate how much N% of a certain width are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the StackPanel and put a Grid with one row and 4 column,  That will do the trick. You can resize the control and it will behave properly. Bellow code the ColumnDefinition Width is actually a Percentage value. for example the first rectangle bellow takes 20% of the total width because the ColumnDefinition set 0.2* on that column.

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.45*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Black" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Black" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Fill="Black" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Grid>
```